# How to connect to Socket.IO swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, socket.io

I am having trouble connecting to Socket.IO chat..

```
import UIKit
import SocketIO

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "wss://socket-io-chat.now.sh/socket.io/")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
        let socket = manager.defaultSocket

        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
            print("socket connected")
        }

        socket.on("new message") {data, ack in
            print("new Messages")
        }

        socket.connect()  
    }
}
```

I am using the latest socket.io library and already added app transport in info.plist.

here's what the logs says..

> 2018-01-22 16:56:46.316676+0800 ExampleSocket[6963:2231315] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 40
>   2018-01-22 16:56:46.317249+0800 ExampleSocket[6963:2231315] LOG SocketEngine: Writing poll:  has data: false
>   2018-01-22 16:56:46.317771+0800 ExampleSocket[6963:2231315] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Sending poll:  as type: 2
>   2018-01-22 16:56:46.323959+0800 ExampleSocket[6963:2231318] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
>   2018-01-22 16:56:46.324082+0800 ExampleSocket[6963:2231318] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
>   2018-01-22 16:56:46.330099+0800 ExampleSocket[6963:2231315] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Created POST string: 1:2
>   2018-01-22 16:56:46.330615+0800 ExampleSocket[6963:2231315] LOG SocketEnginePolling: POSTing
>   2018-01-22 16:56:46.330744+0800 ExampleSocket[6963:2231315] LOG SocketEngine: Engine is being released

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below code:

var socketClient: SocketIOClient!

```
if let url = URL(string: "wss://socket-io-chat.now.sh/socket.io/") {
            let socketClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: url, config: [.log(true),.forcePolling(true)])

            socketClient.connect()
        }


socketClient.onAny { (socEvent) in


if let status =  socEvent.items as? [SocketIO.SocketIOClientStatus] {
            if let first = status.first {
                switch first {
                case .connected:
                    print("Socket: connected")
                    break

                case .disconnected:
                    print("Socket: disconnected")
                    break
                case .notConnected:
                    print("Socket: notConnected")
                    break
                case .connecting:
                    print("Socket: connecting")
                    break
                }
             }
          }
        }
```